# Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed error

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Can someone help me with tuhis issue?

```
CREATE TABLE PATOLOGIE(
    id_patologia int PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    nome varchar(40) NOT NULL
)ENGINE= InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE RICOVERO(
    paziente int NOT NULL, 
    reparto int NOT NULL,
    dataora_inizio datetime NOT NULL,
    dataora_fine datetime ,
    esito tinyint,
    score double,
    colore tinyint,
    dataora_obi datetime,
    dataora_triage datetime,
    PRIMARY KEY(reparto, dataora_inizio, paziente),
    FOREIGN KEY (reparto) REFERENCES REPARTI (id_reparto),
    FOREIGN KEY (paziente) REFERENCES ANAGRAFICA (id)
)ENGINE =InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE RICOVERO_PATOLOGIE(
    paziente int NOT NULL, 
    reparto int NOT NULL,
    dataora_inizio datetime NOT NULL,
    patologia int NOT NULL,
    data_patologia date NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (patologia) REFERENCES PATOLOGIE (id_patologia),
    PRIMARY KEY (paziente, reparto, dataora_inizio, patologia)
)ENGINE =InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

ALTER TABLE RICOVERO_PATOLOGIE  
   ADD CONSTRAINT fk_r 
      FOREIGN KEY (paziente, dataora_inizio, reparto) REFERENCES RICOVERO (paziente, dataora_inizio, reparto) 
      ON UPDATE CASCADE 
      ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Comment: Please add the exact error message to your question.

Answer (score 0):

The columns in the `ALTER TABLE` statement are in the wrong order. Change:

```
FOREIGN KEY (paziente, dataora_inizio, reparto) 
REFERENCES RICOVERO (paziente, dataora_inizio, reparto)
```

to:

```
FOREIGN KEY (reparto, dataora_inizio, paziente) 
REFERENCES RICOVERO (reparto, dataora_inizio, paziente)
```

The column order is significant when defining a foreign key.